# In an app created with Expo, swiping doesn't work in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, expo, swipe

I'm developing an app using Expo. I'm developing the app by `prebuild`ing it.

In the Android emulator, the left/right swipe works fine.
However, in the iOS simulator, the left/right swipe doesn't respond at all. Other apps are responding fine except my app.

Is there anything I need to set up for iOS?